# Flatbuffers: Assertion `off && off <= GetSize()' failed

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

Having implemented my "bottom up" flatbuffers encoder I get the following error message:

```
../../flatbuffers-master/include/flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h:804: flatbuffers::uoffset_t flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder::ReferTo(flatbuffers::uoffset_t): Assertion `off && off <= GetSize()' failed.
```

I believe this may be because I am destroying the builder after I have written each `flatbuffers::Offset<MyTable>` into an array and therefore that table builder cannot later have a this set of functions related to it?  Is the most efficient way to solve this error to have an array of builders?

Currently I am clearing my `latbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder` in between creating each flatbuffers::Offset using my `MyTableBuilder` because this prevented me from getting a nesting error.

This is my third post trying to understand flatbuffers, I am grateful for your support.

Comment: Adding code that illustrates what you're doing in addition to the error would help considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be clearing the `FlatBufferBuilder`: it is responsible for creation of a single buffer, and it must out-live all table builders for all tables that go inside it. If you clear a `FlatBufferBuilder`, you're throwing away any previously serialized data, and offsets are now invalid.

Instead, you should fix the original "nesting error". You get a nesting error if you attempt to create strings, vectors, and sub-tables in-between the start of a parent table builder and `Finish`. Instead, create those items before the start of the parent table builder, save their offsets, and only then start the parent table builder.